# can @Pointcut and @Around in different classes?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I am new to AOP.I made a generic logging API with the help of AOP in which advices are defined.

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StopWatch;


@Component
@Aspect
public class LogExecutionTime {
  private static final String LOG_MESSAGE_FORMAT = "%s.%s execution time: %dms";
  private static final Log LOG =   LogFactory.getLog(LogExecutionTime.class);

  @Around("myPointCut()")
  public Object logTimeMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Inside aAdvice LogExecutionTime");
    StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
    stopWatch.start();
    Object retVal = joinPoint.proceed();
    stopWatch.stop();
    logExecutionTime(joinPoint, stopWatch);
    return retVal;
  }
  private void logExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, StopWatch stopWatch) {
    String logMessage = String.format(LOG_MESSAGE_FORMAT, joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName(), joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    LOG.info(logMessage.toString());
  }
}
```

Now I have included this jar in my application code and written pointcuts.

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Aspect
public class ButterflyPointCut {

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.*.Abc.methodName(..))")
    public void myPointCut(){ 
        System.out.println("Executed");
    }

}
```

It is giving following error.I want to know whether it is because of different classes.I have put the package of jar in component scan.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut myPointCut
        at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:217)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:169)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:220)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:279)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:311)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:119)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:89)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:70)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:346)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:298)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1588)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        ... 57 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the full qualified name of the pointcut method (which you have defined in a separate class) with around annotation.
for example :

here you need to mention the full qualified name of the pointcut method with around annotation
for eg. @Around("domain.package.class.myPointCutMethodName()")

```
@Around("domain.package.className.myPointCut()")
  public Object logTimeMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Inside aAdvice LogExecutionTime");
    StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
    stopWatch.start();
    Object retVal = joinPoint.proceed();
    stopWatch.stop();
    logExecutionTime(joinPoint, stopWatch);
    return retVal;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Yes the exception is due to the annotated methods in different
>   classes.

Keep `@Pointcut` annotated method and `@Around` annotated method in a same class, Other wise use point cut expression inside `@Around` annotation itself like.

```
@Around("execution(* com.*.Abc.methodName(..))")
```